# python for loop random

Tags: python, random

```
lst = ['mylist1','mylist2','mylist3']
for x in lst:
    for r in xrange(2):
        print x
```

Output:( repeat element from list twice )

```
[root@localhost ~]# python test.py
mylist1
mylist1
mylist2
mylist2
mylist3
mylist3
```

how to random element to :

```
mylist3
mylist1
mylist3
mylist2
mylist2
mylist1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or `*` (multiplying operator):

```
lst = lst*2 # repeat items twice
shuffle(lst)
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
lst = [x for i in range(2) for x in lst] # repeat items twice
shuffle(lst)
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could first double-up each elements in the list using list `extend()`, then shuffle the list

```
from random import shuffle

lst = ['mylist1','mylist2','mylist3']
lst = lst.extend(lst) # repeat items twice
shuffle(lst)
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

Comment: For doubling, you can do just `lst = lst.extend(lst)`

Comment: Thank you for your help Andreas and  @FreundAllein

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."